# Is signing the NPT mandatory to join the NSG?

Tags: international-relations, foreign-policy

One of the objections raised by China in preventing India join the Nuclear Suppliers Group (NSG) is that India has not yet signed the Non-Proliferation Treaty (NPT), nor is it willing to. India has made a counter-claim that signing the NPT is not mandatory to join the NSG, and has given the example of France which was not party to the NPT when it joined the NSG. (http://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-news-india/npt-not-required-for-nuclear-suppliers-group-membership-india/)

So, is signing the NPT mandatory to join the NSG or not? Who's right here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to participate in the Nuclear Supplies Group (NSG), [these factors are taken into account](http://www.nuclearsuppliersgroup.org/en/participants1):

> Factors taken into account for participation include the following:
>
> - The ability to supply items (including items in transit) covered by the Annexes to Parts 1 and 2 of the NSG Guidelines;
> - Adherence to the Guidelines and action in accordance with them;
> - Enforcement of a legally based domestic export control system which gives effect to the commitment to act in accordance with the Guidelines;
> - Adherence to one or more of the NPT, the Treaties of Pelindaba, Rarotonga, Tlatelolco, Bangkok , Semipalatinsk or an equivalent international nuclear non-proliferation agreement, and full compliance with the obligations of such agreement(s);
> - Support of international efforts towards non-proliferation of weapons of mass destruction and of their delivery vehicles.

A country has to adhere to any one of the various international nuclear non-proliferation agreement as one of the criteria.

Regarding France's case, the country's one of the initial 7 participating governments and one of the reasons for the creation of the NSG was to allow non-NPT signatories to join, specifically France at that time.

However, it's unclear whether a non-NPT signatory can still join the NSG now and the group had held a special meeting last year to discuss this, however [no consensus was achieved](https://www.dawn.com/news/1296891).

> On 11 November, the Nuclear Suppliers Group held a special meeting in Vienna to discuss criteria for India’s entry. China continued to block India’s entry into the NSG, citing the need for a non-discriminatory solution to admit non-NPT members.

Comment: And have India signed any of those non-proliferation treaties (Pelindaba, Bangkok, etc), even if not NPT itself ?